# Is the sequence of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules $0\to f_*\mathcal I\to f_*\mathcal O_X\to f_*(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal I)\to 0$ exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes and $\mathcal I$ a quasi-coherent sheaf of ideals of $\mathcal O_X$, then we have an exact sequence of $\mathcal O_X$-modules $$0\to \mathcal I\to \mathcal O_X\to \mathcal O_X/\mathcal I\to 0$$, it induces the sequence of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules  $$0\to f_*\mathcal I\to f_*\mathcal O_X\to f_*(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal I)\to 0$$,  is it exact?

If the answer is not, we suppose $X,Y$ are Noetherian, is the sequence of $\mathcal O_Y$-modules  $0\to f_*\mathcal I\to f_*\mathcal O_X\to f_*(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal I)\to 0$ exact?

Comment: Have you tried the case $X=\mathbb{P}^1_k, Y=\mathrm{Spec}\, k$?

Comment: @Mohan Can you give more details?

Comment: An ideal sheaf (non-zero) in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ is of the form$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n)$ some integer $n\geq 0$. Applying $f_*$ where $f:\mathbb{P}^1_k\to\mathrm{Spec}\, k$ is the structure morphism is just taking global sections. So, you get an exact sequence, $0\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n))\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})\to H^0(\mathcal{O}_Z)\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-n))\to 0$, where $Z$ is a scheme of length $n$. If $n\geq 2$, thus you get the map is not surjective.